# Uploadify Alert after upload not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, uploadify

I am using uploadify and this is my current code:

```
<link href="/uploader/uploadify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/uploader/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/uploader/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/uploader/jquery.uploadify.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
'uploader' : '/uploader/uploadify.php',
'swf' : '/uploader/uploadify.swf',
'cancelImage' : '/uploader/uploadify-cancel.png',
'auto' : true,

'onUploadComplete' : function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
alert('There are ' + data.fileCount + ' files remaining in the queue.');
}
});

});
</script>
```

I'm I forgetting something here?

Comment: Which version of uploadify you are using ? I didnt find any 'onUploadComplete'. They have 'onComplete' Checkout here http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
eval('var answer = '+response+';');
console.log(answer);
```

You can also view actual arguments of the method using:

```
console.log(arguments)
```